# laravel elqouent create method cant be overrriden

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, laravel-5.4

I need to maintain store serial number of topics in db user wise unique, so  instead of calculating each time I want to override eloquent create method as

in **App\Topic.php**

```
public static function create(array $data)
{
    //some logic here  
    parent::create($data);
}
```

But whenever I run call `Topic::create($data)` method, it fails silently and `500 error` comes on the browser no laravel exception thrown, when I run on tinker, it automatically get an exit , I was unable to find a log where I need to look for this issue

What can be a problem here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should do this in the model event instead of overwriting the methods. It does exactly what you need.

```
public static function boot()
{
    parent::boot();

    static::creating(function($model) {
        // make some changes or log or whatever you want
    });
}
```

You can even move the logic to a custom observer class. Read more about it here https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/eloquent#events

Comment: i need to alter data before create and if that works i was going to create trait to be used by other model ,

Comment: Everything you plan to do with overriding the `create` method can be done with this. You can alter the data before creating and you can use a common trait to reuse the event handler.

Comment: @ddw147 post the actual logic you perform and i'll show you how you could do the same with this.

Comment: i have create trait like this https://gist.github.com/ddw147/3f09d2f803bebe27c6895e38b18cb6cf
without using parent call , its working now, you can get idea from that

Comment: @ddw147 https://pastebin.com/W9DA7dTp That's exactly what your code with what i recommended would look like. Looks cleaner?

Comment: yes got that, I have also done something like that but forgot    parent::boot();